# how to fill in the desired result column like the table above

Tags: excel, search

| RESULT | SOURCE |
| --- | --- |
| 100 Mbps | internet Fair Usage 2.0 Speed 100 Mbps ~ E22010[705000] - C16059 |
| 300 Mbps | Internet Fair Usage 2.0 Speed 300 Mbps ~ E22010[405000] - C16059 |

```
how to fill in the desired result column like the table above
```

Comment: Hi @Daniel, Can you pls provide more details to your question?.

Answer (score 0):

For sample data you can try-

```
=TEXTAFTER(TEXTBEFORE(B2," ~")," ",-2)
```

[image]